# Calling method inside the same class: Uncaught type error: this.hide_controls is not a function

Tags: ecmascript-6

**ECMAScript 6**

In html I have button with id="update" and some other control elements with class="control". When I press "Update" button, other controls should disappear.

When I press the "Update" button, I get: "Uncaught type error: this.hide_controls is not a function".

This may help: if I stop at the breakpoint (see "debugger" in the code), then "this" equals to button#update.btn.btn-default.control.

**Could you help me call hide_controls method.**

```
class ButtonManager{

    constructor (){
        this.init_main_object_buttons();
    }

    init_main_object_buttons(){
        this._main_object_update_button = $("#update");
        this._main_object_update_button.click(this.update_main_object);
        this._controls = $(".control");
    }

    hide_controls(){

        this._controls.addClass("hide");
    }

    update_main_object(){
        debugger;
        this.hide_controls();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Class methods do not autobind. It works exactly the same as in ES5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

`this._main_object_update_button.click(this.update_main_object);`

to this

`this._main_object_update_button.click(this.update_main_object.bind(this));`

This will bind the scope of the method call to your current instance.
`this` will equal an instance of `ButtonManager` just how you'd want it to be.